# WebSocket Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: apache-2.4, socket

Due to WebSocket connections I am facing issue and due to this other response to stop receiving.

I have configured BIMServer to response back to my application and render 3D view loading individual component on viewer(pop-up window).

I am receiving below error in google chrome.

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://?/bimserver/stream' failed: Connection
>   closed before receiving a handshake response

What I had tried.

I have tried to redirect this request in apache 2.4.7 by using `proxyPass` and redirect to the actual address with IP.

I wanted to know how we can configure it apache2.4.7 to ignore wss request.

Comment: Shouldn't that URL have a hostname in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this meets your problem completely. But the WebSocket Connection error can be resolved by using the [ReconnectingWebSocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket) script by joewalnes.